# Android - cannot populate a TableView with JSONArray data

Tags: android, json, tablelayout

i'm tryng to populate a TableLayout witth data that i get from a MySql database, i get the data from a php script that execute the query and return a JSONArray.

The query seem to work and i get a correct JSONArray, but i get a NullPointerExeption while running this code:

```
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.layout.list);
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            TextView title = new TextView(this);
            TextView author = new TextView(this);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    title.setText(json_data.getString("title").toString());
                    author.setText(json_data.getString("author").toString());

                    tr.addView(title);
                    tr.addView(author);

                    tl.addView(tr);
                    tr.removeAllViews();
            }
```

"result" contain a valid JSONArray, probably something go wrong in the for cycle, but i don't understand where is the error!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where do you get the Exception? On which line of the code?

Comment: the lines to create a new object of the `tr`, `title` and `author` objects should move in the loop. Also no need to run `removeAllViews`.

Comment: While not directly answering your question, replacing `json_data.getString("title").toString()` with `String.valueOf(json_data.getString("title"))` will prevent NPE if getString() returns null.